# USB tethering on Ubuntu Server 18.0.4.1 with Lubuntu Core only

Tags: ubuntu, usb, android, ubuntu-server, tethering

i have installed (on laptop) on top of Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 the following only:
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core lxappearance obconf

when i connect my Android phone it shows in file manager but if I enable USB tethering in the phone, the operating system does not show the creation of a new network interface corresponding to the connectivity with the phone.
with same phone USB tethering works on other Linux installs.

please advise what packages i need to install to make USB tethering work.
thank you

as update i found that a new network interface is created:
4: enp0s20u5u1:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:d0:a0:7e:a3:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

but the interface is DOWN. no IP assigned.
found:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1364032&highlight=tethering

looks like the package managing the tethering is usbmuxd

Comment: off the top of my head, they use RNDIS and it should work with a defaultish install of ubuntu server. I don't have any default ones though, since I've been ripping out netplan from them for my needs.